# Windows Batch Scripting: Parse CSV file and extract data with space

Tags: batch-file

I have a `csv` file such as below

```
Name,Test User1  
Name2,TstUser Two  
Name3,Test User Three
```

I need to extract the `Test User1` in to a Variable in a batch file,and other variables similarly to different variables.

Comment: No i need to fetch the data with spaces

Comment: Then get rid of the space in the `delims` section of the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=," %%a in (file.csv) do set "_%%a=%%b"
echo your variables are:
set_
```

Output with your example data:

```
your variables are:
_Name=Test User1
_Name2=TstUser Two
_Name3=Test User Three
```

**Edit** to get a single line/variable only:

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%a in ('type file.csv^|findstr /bi "Name,"') do set "Name=%%a"
echo %Name%
```

Comment: My requirement is to get just the **Test User1** in to `%%a`

Comment: Sorry, I understood `and other variables similarly to different variables` wrong then. See my edit (I left the original code, because it may help future searchers)

Comment: `for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%a in ('type file.csv^|findstr /bi "Name,"') do set "Name=%%a"`  This solution did not help me as i only get 'Test' as the output and not **Test User1 **

Comment: That can only happen, if you either have `...delims=, "` or no delims at all (relying on the standard delimiters). `"tokens=2 delims=,"` correctly gives `Test User1`.

Comment: Sorry My bad , your solution is absolutely works for me.Thank you